# Oracle Create Index with DBMS_SQL.Parse

Tags: oracle, indexing, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I am Trying to Create Index like this below:

```
DECLARE l_cursor NUMBER;
  l_return NUMBER;
  v_stmt CLOB;
BEGIN
  v_stmt:= TO_CLOB('CREATE INDEX IX_Job ON "JOBSTEP"("JOBID") TABLESPACE "USERS";');
  l_cursor  := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;
  DBMS_SQL.parse(l_cursor, v_stmt, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(l_cursor);  
END;
```

Please find the below error on executing :

> ORA-02158: invalid CREATE INDEX option
>
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1185 ORA-06512: at line 7
>   02158. 00000 -  "invalid CREATE INDEX option"
>   *Cause:    An option other than COMPRESS, NOCOMPRESS, PCTFREE, INITRANS,
>              MAXTRANS, STORAGE, TABLESPACE, PARALLEL, NOPARALLEL, RECOVERABLE,
>              UNRECOVERABLE, LOGGING, NOLOGGING, LOCAL, or GLOBAL was specified.
>   *Action:   Choose one of the valid CREATE INDEX options.

If i execute `CREATE INDEX IX_Job ON "JOBSTEP"("JOBID") TABLESPACE "USERS";` like this Index is getting created.

Using Oracle 12c, I tried all this using sql developer.
Please someone help me to resolve this. Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Why do you not simply use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_stmt;`?

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end of `v_stmt`;

Comment: Do not end your `create index` statement with semicolon - this is the cause of the error. Plus. there is no need to use `TO_CLOB()` function. And finally, there is absolutely no need to use dynamic SQL at all. Use static SQL.

Comment: I can't use that because i will be executing more than 1 lakh characters in that statement which not possible with "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov thanks it worked by removing semicolon.

Comment: EXECUTE IMMEDIATE accepts also CLOB parameters, see [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS1188): *String literal, string variable, or string expression that represents a SQL statement. Its type must be either CHAR, VARCHAR2, or **CLOB**.*

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov this code i will be executing through EntityFramwork' ExecuteStoreCommand. If i use Static SQL code directly it is failing so we started wrapping inside Begin & End. we have problem as we can't write DDL statements directly inside Begin & End. So next option we have Dynamic SQL.

Comment: Dynamic SQL seems to be OK but using `DBMS_SQL` is useless and waste of (coding-) time.

Comment: Interesting discussion on ‘DBMS_SQL vs. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE’. Though, I personally use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (perhaps like many others) whenever I am unable to get the job done thru static SQL, here I could see relevant notes in favour on DBMS_SQL :-

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/o67asktom-101004.html
http://www.toadworld.com/products/toad-for-oracle/w/toad_for_oracle_wiki/231.dbms-sql-vs-execute-immediate


Though, DBMS_SQL requires more typing/coding but gives you more control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from the question helped by removing the semicolon from the v_stmt line.

Here's the updated code

```
DECLARE l_cursor NUMBER;
l_return NUMBER;
v_stmt CLOB;
BEGIN
  v_stmt:= TO_CLOB('CREATE INDEX IX_Job ON "JOBSTEP"("JOBID") TABLESPACE "USERS"');
  l_cursor  := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;
  DBMS_SQL.parse(l_cursor, v_stmt, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
  DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(l_cursor);  
END;
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why is it not allowed to use a semicolon at the end of a create index statement? It doesn't seem to make any sense.